# Segmentation fault on Dining Philosophers in C with Pthreads

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I have this segmentation fault problem in the exercise of the dining philosophers with one thread per philosopher which I can't manage. Each threads think for a random period of time and same with eat. Each philosopher can eat with two forks, he has to pick both forks to eat. To avoid deadlock I made a sort for the picking forks. The philosophers with odd number pick the right fork first. I used a global semaphore which I initialize with the function init at the start of main. Is there someone who can help me please? I tried to put some fprintf(stderr,"HERE\n") but because of concurrency I can't find the problem. Here is the code

'''

```
//global array of semaphore
 pthread_mutex_t *mtx;

//intialize array of semaphore
void init(pthread_mutex_t *mtx){
    mtx=malloc(N*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    if(!mtx){
      perror("malloc fallita\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
     if(pthread_mutex_init(&mtx[i],NULL) != 0){
         perror("init fallita\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   }
 } 



void eat(unsigned int *seed){
  long r = rand_r(seed) % 800000;
  struct timespec t={0,r};
  nanosleep(&t,NULL);
}

void think(unsigned int *seed){
long r = rand_r(seed) % 1000000;
struct timespec t={0,r};
nanosleep(&t,NULL);
}


void *filosofo(void *arg){
    unsigned int id = *((unsigned int*)arg);
    unsigned int seed=id;
    int left = id % N;
    int right = id-1;
    while(1){
        think(&seed);
        if(id % 2){ //il filosofo di indice dispari prende prima la forchetta di destra
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx[right]);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx[left]);
            eat(&seed);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx[left]);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx[right]);
        }else{ //il filosofo di indice pari prende prima la forchetta a sinista
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx[left]);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx[right]);
            eat(&seed);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx[right]);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx[left]);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(void){
    init(mtx);
    //array of N philosophers
    pthread_t *th;
    th = malloc(N*sizeof(pthread_t));
    if(!th){
        perror("Malloc fallita\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,filosofo,(void*)(intptr_t)i) != 0){
            perror("create fallita\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(pthread_join(th[i],NULL) == -1){
            perror("join fallita\n");
        }
    }

    free(th);
    free(mtx);

    return 0;

}
```

'''

Comment: Did you run it with a debugger? The debugger will tell you _where_ exactly the segfault happens.

Comment: You have two variables named `mtx`: one global, and one in `init`. You never change the former, so `mtx[right]` in `filosofo` dereferences a NULL pointer.

Comment: Please don't add `[SOLVED]` to your title once you have fixed the problem. It's considered unnecessary and quite a few people frown upon it.

Comment: ... instead, accept one answer by clicking the check mark next to it.  If appropriate, you may write an answer to accept yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `init` take a pointer to a pointer to a mutex to initialize. Currently, the global `mtx` isn't changed.

Here's roughly how:

```
void init(pthread_mutex_t **mtx){ // pointer to pointer
    *mtx=malloc(N*sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)); // dereference
    if(!*mtx){
      perror("malloc fallita\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
     if(pthread_mutex_init(&(*mtx)[i],NULL) != 0){ // pointer acrobatics
         perror("init fallita\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
   }
 }
```

and then pass a pointer to the global `mtx` in `main`:

```
int main(void){
    init(&mtx);
```

I suggest naming your global mutex and your local mutex in `init` differently so this doesn't confuse you again.

Also, right here you're passing the value of `i` as a `void *`, instead of passing its address:

```
        if(pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,filosofo,(void*)(intptr_t)i) != 0){
```

If you do this (which I actually recommend to avoid race conditions), then you should change `filosofo` to take input in the same way:

```
unsigned int id = (unsigned int)arg;
```

Comment: Alternatively, get rid of the parameter and just use the global everywhere.

Comment: I tried to do both ways you told me but same problem. I have changed this ' void init(pthread_mutex_t **sem) ' and deferencing all the occurences inside the function with ' (*sem) '

Comment: @DylanNico You have to do both.

Comment: I finally got it, in addition to your suggestion, there was another error. I passed the argument with 'void(*)i' but was '(void*)(&i). And in the function 'filososo()' you have to deference it. Thanks: anyone knows why in the comment i can't use code ?

Comment: @DylanNico If my answer helped you, please click the checkmark on the side to accept it. This helps me earn privileges so I can improve the quality of content on the site.